# HTML 5 check field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a this form:

```
<html>
<form name=“test” action=“test.php”>

<input type=“text” name=“surname” pattern=“.{3,}>”
<input type=“submit” value=“send”>

</form>
```

I want that the “surname” field has at least 3 characters and for this reason I added the `pattern` attribute (I use HTML5) but in this way I check this every time the user clicks the "send" button while I want to check this every time the user edits the "surname" field without using javascript but only HTML5.
Is it possible?

Comment: If you don't use javascript, then IMO you shouldn't use the javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

you need to add client-side javascript to your form before php processing,

to check the input sequence or pattern of letters and numbers you need to add a regular expression to check the value of the input

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible without using JavaScript. See the [HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) for more details. However you can change the CSS as an indication of an invalid value:

```
input[pattern]:invalid { 
  color:red;
}
```